# Move to first 'default' focus of web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Say you have website, and when you refresh it, if you check which element has focus, using this code:

```
setInterval(function () {
    console.log('ID: ', $(document.activeElement).attr('id') + ' Tag: ' + $(document.activeElement).prop('tagName')
        + ' C: ' + $(document.activeElement).attr('class'));
}, 2000);
```

You will see that tag of element is 'BODY' element. How do you restore focus to the same element using javascript because, things like `$('body').focus();` doesn't work.

**EDIT:** It should also reset the 'focus' flow of document. So after you click TAB it will focus the same element as if you would refresh page then click TAB.

**EDIT 2:** I need to reset focus on some action like keyDown, to default state - the state after you load page. From my research I know that element focused after you load page is 'body', and then after you click Tab, the first element in focus flow of your website is focused. I can't do that using $('body').focus(); - it doesn't focus body and doesn't reset current flow of focus of document.

**EDIT 3:** So far We have managed to somehow reset focus to `body` element of website using this code: `document.activeElement.blur();` so my above script would say that `body` is focused, but it doesn't reset the actual flow of current focus, when you use keyboard to navigate website (TAB button). It's possible to have workaround and select specified element you want, but that's not answer to question. What is general purpose mechanism to reset flow of keyboard navigation of website to default state, without refreshing a page?

**EDIT 4:** https://jsfiddle.net/4qjb5asw/5/

Comment: how does one focus on body?

Comment: Not sure but `.focus()` only works with input fields?

Comment: Apparently browser does it, when you refresh page.

Comment: What kind of Tab are your using? Bootstrap? if so, they have document to active a event on switching tabs

Comment: actually you question is: you want stop focusing an element on `keydown` or `Tab active`, you want keep something else focused, no matter what user did. right?

Answer (score 5):

Rather than specifically focusing the `<body>`, you can clear the focus of the active element by doing `document.activeElement.blur();` This should restore focus to the `<body>` element and reset the focus flow.

Click around in the snippet below to see what the current `document.activeElement` is.

```js
$("#reset").on("click", function() {
  document.activeElement.blur();
  logActiveElement();
});

$("form").children().on("focus", logActiveElement);

function logActiveElement() {
    console.log("The active element is now: " + $(document.activeElement).prop('tagName'));
}
```

```css
.blur {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" />
  <textarea></textarea>
  <button type="button">Test Button</button>
</form>

<div class="blur">
  <button id="reset">RESET ACTIVE ELEMENT</button>
</div>
```

Comment: It does not reset the focus flow to default of document, see:
https://jsfiddle.net/4qjb5asw/5/ Move, using TAB to Y input, then click ESCAPE button to fire action, then click TAB - it will move to Z input, I want it to reset focus flow too, so X input should be focused.

Comment: @user3157855 Just curious, which browser are you using? It's difficult to replicate using things like JSFiddle because the focus for me returns to the external elements rather than those contained to the snippet.

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you are just looking to reset the default focus for the document on certain events like `keydown` on a particular key so that the user can begin tabbing through the document from the top after triggering the event.

You can reset the default focus for the document with:

`document.activeElement.blur()`

You can add any event listener you want to trigger the function. For the `keydown` event on the escape key it would be:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  if (event.key === 'Escape') {
    document.activeElement.blur()
  }
});
```

IMPORTANT: Note that if you are testing this in an embedded tool like an SO snippet or jsfiddle, you will need to add a little more code to set the focus to the element wrapper for that tool to emulate what would happen if the display area represented the entire document (otherwise, you will reset the focus to the main document and in the case of SO you will start tabbing through the menus, question, answers, comments, and other elements on the page before you get to the snippet).

Example snippet for testing that will reset the focus to the wrapper element in the snippet so that tabbing will restart from the beginning of the snippet (and not from the beginning of the document for this SO page):

```js
/*
 * All code below referencing the "snippet" variable is only
 * here to help us pretend that the snippet result
 * represents the entire document (not needed in a
 * regular implementation).
 */
const snippet = document.querySelector('#snippet');
snippet.focus();

const btn = document.querySelector('#button1');
const resetFocus = () => {
  document.activeElement.blur();
  snippet.focus();
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  if (event.key === 'Escape') {
    resetFocus();
  }
});

btn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  resetFocus();
});
```

```html
<!--
  The "snippet" wrapper div with tabindex attribute
  is only here to help us pretend that the snippet result
  represents the entire document (not needed in a regular
  implementation). The tabindex helps ensure that the
  wrapper div is focusable.
-->

<div id="snippet" tabindex="0">
  <div>Tab to or select input to focus. To reset focus:
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li>Press escape key.</li>
    <li>Or, click "Reset" button.</li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <input id="input1" type="text" name="input1" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="input2" type="text" name="input2" />
  </div>
  <button id="button1">Reset</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want granular control of focus, consider using the `tabIndex` [1] property. Basically, it allows you to specify tab order by assigning numbers to each of the elements which can have focus. An added benefit is that `tabIndex` enables you to specify elements to take which may not be by default--exactly what you need.

Tab order and focus is extremely important for accessibility, since User does not have a pointing device. So, this tag is designed to give you precise control of focus. It enables you to specify all focus-able elements on your page. In your case, it provides a handle to all focus-able elements, enabling you to specifically set focus where you need it, when you need it.

Not sure which framework you're using, but jQuery is a candidate for cross-browser compatibility.

From the `jQuery .focus()` page:

> In recent browser versions, the event can be extended to include all
>   element types by explicitly setting the element's tabindex property. [2]

Perhaps `.focus()` based on tabindex; Something like this:

```
$('input[tabindex='+ntabindex+']').focus();  // [3]
```

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex
2. https://api.jquery.com/focus/
3. https://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-focus-on-next-object-according-to-tab-index-not-object-order-on-page

Just be sure to check your tab order if using this feature. Tab through your page and make sure you've got all the focus-able elements properly ordered.

Comment: That's useful info but, doesn't really answer my question. What if you have many elements set 'tabindex=0' (the order will be from first to last element in tabindex=0 elements group)? I need general purpose mechanism, forget about manually setting the order or element. I could just reset focus then use function `.live()`, on keyup/down event with tab to set exact element, but that's workaround only not perfect answer to my question.

Comment: It describes how to manually manage focus, and gives you the knowledge you need to build a working solution. Nothing is ever perfect, my friend, and you get what you pay for :P

Answer (score 2):

I have a header `div` element at the top of the page. Each time new content is loaded onto the page, I want to move focus back to the header, given it is at the top of the document,

```
<div tabindex="-1" role="header">
  <a href="#content">I always want this to be tabbed first</a>
</div>
```

The important point is setting `tabindex` to `-1` which removes it from the default focus flow of the browser and allows me to then programmatically set focus using javascript.

```
document.querySelector('div[role="header"]').focus();
```

This snippet is ran every time new content is shown and means people using keyboards get a consistent start point for each page in a single page application.

Now when I hit the tab key, the `<a>` tag is always focussed first.

Answer (score 1):

Your question can be splitted into three parts

- find the default focus element of a website.
- focus on a element
- control of next focus element

If you have control to the element on screen, or if it is predictable static. a simple `document.querySelector("#id").focus()` will focus the default element.

If it is not the case, you need some detection which could be complicated.

Browser will first find element with smallest positive non-zero `[tabIndex]` number.
Than if `#anchor` is present, it use first focusable element after it.
Otherwise first focusable element `a[href],button,input,object,area[href]` from body.

As you might not want to focus on the element, but want it to be focus next.
You can inject a invisible element just before it, with anoptional tabIndex hack, and focus on your invisible element.
and dismiss the injected element on blur.

Comment: Thanks, that's good workaround, but still workaround. I'm also using some other workaround to make it actually work ( `.live()` function on keyup/down event after `.activeElement.blur()`). Is there really no way to tell browser to reset it's focus flow to default without refreshing page?

Answer (score 0):

this will keep your specified element focused

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
     var focusbox = document.getElementById("element_to_focus");
     focusbox.focus();
    });
})
```

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. I need to reset focus on some action like keyDown, default state - the state after you load page. From my research I know that element focused after you load page is 'body', and then after you click Tab, the first element in focus flow of your website is focused. I can't do that using `$('body').focus();` - it doesn't focus body and doesn't reset flow of focus of document.

Comment: @user3157855 actually you question is: you want stop focusing an element on keydown or Tab active, you want keep something else focused, no matter what user did. right?

Answer (score 0):

The "snippet" wrapper div with a tabindex attribute
  is only here to help us pretend that the snippet result represents the entire document (not needed in a regular implementation). The tab index helps ensure that the wrapper div is focusable.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't leave links under your posts; those might be perceived as spam.

Answer (score 0):

Create a link with `href="#"` and `style="display: none; position: absolute;"` at the beginning of your body.
When you want to reset the focus: show the element, focus it and hide it back.

Answer (score 0):

Restoring the initial keyboard tab order of focus was the same problem I had. As others have posted, `document.activeElement.blur()` would set the body as the current focus. Unfortunately, on subsequent tabbing-through, the browser would always skip back and remember the last tabbed item before blur().

What ultimately worked for me was similar to Dan's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/61566372/13175620). You create a temporary anchor tag to focus, add it as the first child of `<body>`, set focus to that element, and then remove the tag. This works in both Chrome and Firefox

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
  // Used to reset tab-index flow
  if (e.key === 'Escape') {
    var a = document.createElement('a')
    a.href = '#'
    a.style.position = 'absolute'
    a.style.width = '1px'
    a.style.height = '1px'
    a.style.overflow = 'hidden'
    document.body.prepend(a)
    a.focus()
    document.body.removeChild(a)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by defining a focus-resetting ‹div› with `tabindex="-1"` which you'll then actively focus on-escape.

```js
document.onkeydown = function (evt) {
  if (evt.which == 27) // On Escape button press 
  {
    document.querySelector('#focus-reset').focus();
  }
}
```

```css
#focus-reset {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="focus-reset" tabindex="-1">
      <form>
        <label>X:</label><input type="text"/>
        <label>Y:</label><input type="text"/>
        <label>Z:</label><input type="text"/>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```